# Node that was not modified fails to build

Tags: frame, error

I had a *fully functioning* node that was built about 4 day ago and I was using it. Today I've decided to *rebuild* it with `cargo build -r` and for some reason if failed to build with absolutely weird error message saying:

```
   Compiling libp2p-floodsub v0.31.0
   Compiling libp2p-relay v0.4.0
   Compiling libp2p-rendezvous v0.1.0
   Compiling libp2p-noise v0.33.0
   Compiling soketto v0.7.1
   Compiling sc-network v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.19#174735ea)
   Compiling librocksdb-sys v0.6.1+6.28.2
   Compiling multihash v0.14.0
error[E0603]: module `group` is private
   --> /home/creestl/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/174735e/frame/support/procedural/tools/src/syn_ext.rs:50:53
    |
50  |                 let syn::group::$name { token, content } = syn::group::$parse(input)?;
    |                                                                 ^^^^^ private module
    |
note: the module `group` is defined here
   --> /home/creestl/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.98/src/lib.rs:304:1
    |
304 | mod group;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0603]: module `group` is private
   --> /home/creestl/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/174735e/frame/support/procedural/tools/src/syn_ext.rs:50:14
    |
50  |                 let syn::group::$name { token, content } = syn::group::$parse(input)?;
    |                          ^^^^^ private module
    |
note: the module `group` is defined here
   --> /home/creestl/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/syn-1.0.98/src/lib.rs:304:1
    |
304 | mod group;
    | ^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0603`.
error: could not compile `frame-support-procedural-tools` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Once again, I **did not** modify anything in the code. I did not update cargo or rustup.
I've tried building on the other computer and the result is the same.
I've tried to checkout one of the previous commits that was 100% working and the build failed again
Also I'm explicitly specifying `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.19"` in my .toml files to keep all versions the same.

I literally have no idea why that could happen. For several months everything was fine.

You can try to reproduce the error using [my code](https://github.com/CREESTL/Crain)

What might be the reason for such an error?

Answer (score 1):

See [this issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11706)
That was fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11707)

For easy fix just add

```
syn = { version = "=1.0.82" }
```

to your runtime's `Cargo.toml` and rebuild