# Error building the parachain template - 2

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rust, build, cargo

I was compiling the runtime by cloning this source, https://github.com/szout/substrate-parachain-template, but at the moment I met this issue.

[image]

I tried to solve this issue by referencing these QAs, but none of them helped me.

[Error Building Substrate contract Node(error[E0603]: module `group` is private) After switching Substrate dependencies to "polkadot-v0.9.23"](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3479/error-building-substrate-contract-nodeerrore0603-module-group-is-private)

[Node that was not modified fails to build](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/node-that-was-not-modified-fails-to-build)

[Substrate Node Template Build Error, syn::group private](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/substrate-node-template-build-error-syngroup-private/4312#4312)

So I added this phrase in the runtime/Cargo.toml to solve the issue, and it worked for me;
syn = { version = "=1.0.82"}

'**But after adding it, I faced another error like below while building the runtime.**'

[image]

'**Are here anyones who can guide me?**'

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help me.

Comment: You should provide more detail. Why it didn't help you? What is the new error?

Comment: I have tried all instructions in the links I mentioned, but I could not solve the issue I'd faced. It seems the issue is related the open source's version, I guess, but am not sure.

Comment: I tried to reset the parity-db version, to remove the checksum section in Cargo.lock file, but it didn't work while in the *.lock file being 2 "syn" parts.

Comment: Did you read that post? You don't need to modify the lock file yourself. You just need to use the `cargo update` command to manage them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140364/discussion-between-tinydev-and-aurevoirxavier).