# file not found for module `sys`

Tags: substrate-node-template, babe

Geeting following error's how can i fix this error?

```rs
     error[E0583]: file not found for module `sys`
        --> /Users/abubakarmujahid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:26:1
         |
      26 | mod sys;
         | ^^^^^^^^
         |
         = help: to create the module `sys`, create file "/Users/abubakarmujahid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/errno-0.3.1/src/sys.rs" or "/Users/abubakarmujahid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/errno-0.3.1/src/sys/mod.rs"

      error[E0425]: cannot find function `with_description` in module `sys`
        --> /Users/abubakarmujahid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:47:14
         |
      47 |         sys::with_description(*self, |desc| {
         |    

     

         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`
    
      error[E0425]: cannot find function `with_description` in module `sys`
        --> /Users/abubakarmujahid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:58:14
         |
      58 |         sys::with_description(*self, |desc| match desc {
         |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`

      error[E0425]: cannot find value `STRERROR_NAME` in module `sys`
        --> /Users/abubakarmujahid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:64:22
         |
      64 |                 sys::STRERROR_NAME,
         |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`

 

     error[E0425]: cannot find function `errno` in module `sys`
        --> /Users/abubakarmujahid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:95:10
         |
      95 |     sys::errno()
         |          ^^^^^ not found in `sys`

      error[E0425]: cannot find function `set_errno` in module `sys`
         --> /Users/abubakarmujahid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/errno-0.3.1/src/lib.rs:100:10
          |
      100 |     sys::set_errno(err)
          |          ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sys`
```

Comment: check this https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/node-that-was-not-modified-fails-to-build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I cargo.toml file you have to do this there.

pallet-session, instead of features = ["historical"], replace it with default-features = false