# how to solve the sys error in substrate polkadot branch (polkadot-v0.9.43)

Tags: evm, substrate-node, blockchain

I have been  integrating EVM(43 version) in 43  version of substrate. while  adding files to runtime module i am getting sys error while building it .I want to know  how to  solve
this error[image]

Comment: What do you mean 43 version?

Comment: here i am referring it the branch (polkadot-v0.9.43) and same for Evm frontier branch (polkadot-v0.9.43)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your imports, check your `Cargo.toml`.

As an example if you check this previous StackExchange issue: [file not found for module `sys`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8681/file-not-found-for-module-sys).

It worked using the `default-features = false` in `pallet_session` instead of `features = ["historical"]`

Comment: it was similar to that i have missed writing default-features false in one the pallets

Comment: I also got the same error. But cannot understand what you explained here. could you please explain a bit more about how to solve this issue?