# error[E0583]: file not found for module sys

Tags: substrate-node-template

error[E0583]: file not found for module sys

cargo 1.73.0-nightly (7e9de3f4e 2023-08-13)
rustc 1.73.0-nightly (180dffb 2023-08-14)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve the sys error in substrate polkadot branch (polkadot-v0.9.43)](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9399/how-to-solve-the-sys-error-in-substrate-polkadot-branch-polkadot-v0-9-43)

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed here: [how to solve the sys error in substrate polkadot branch (polkadot-v0.9.43)](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9399/how-to-solve-the-sys-error-in-substrate-polkadot-branch-polkadot-v0-9-43/9691#9691), just add in your `Cargo.toml` `default-features = false` when importing the pallet_session